# FIND IN SET in mysql 8.0 - is not working correctly

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    c.Id AS Id,
    ct.Title AS Title,
    cu.Url AS Url,
    c.ImageUrl AS ImageUrl
FROM
    categories c
JOIN
    categorymodelproductmodel pcm ON c.Id = pcm.CategoriesId
INNER JOIN
    products p ON pcm.ProductsId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN
    categorytitles ct ON c.Id = ct.CategoryId
INNER JOIN
    categoryurls cu ON c.Id = cu.CategoryId
WHERE
    c.Type = 'category'
    AND FIND_IN_SET('11589459',  c.Path) = 0
    AND p.BrandId = 167300
    AND p.IsVisible = 1
    AND ct.Language = 'Pl'
    AND cu.Language = 'Pl'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM categories c2
        JOIN categorytitles ct2 ON c2.Id = ct2.CategoryId
        WHERE ct2.Title = ct.Title
            AND c2.Id <> c.Id
    )
GROUP BY
    c.Id, ct.Title, cu.Url, c.ImageUrl;
```

example of column Path in categories table
1052820, 2753794, 1050568

---

query execution returns categories with id=11589459 in the column Path although such categories should be skipped.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: *example of column Path in categories table 1052820, 2753794, 1050568* - Looks like there are spaces after commas.. `'1'` and `' 1'` are different values in CSV list.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but be aware that FIND_IN_SET will return NULL if the c.Path column is NULL. It would be safer to write `AND COALESCE(FIND_IN_SET('11589459',  c.Path), 0) = 0`

Comment: your example is separated by ", " (comma and space); that will not work with find_in_set which just expects commas.  you could do `find_in_set(..., replace(c.Path,' ',''))`

Comment: change the line to **AND FIND_IN_SET('11589459',  c.Path) > 0**. FIND_IN_SET returns the position 1 or 2 or 3 where the needle is found. if not found it return 0

Comment: @Akina You are right!